# R blotter package Why is there no accumulated profit and drawdown on the chart?

Tags: r, trading, algorithmic-trading, blotter

I'm learning a `blotter` and have implemented a tidal strategy. (by the way, please check if I did everything correctly). The strategy can have only one position
1 buy
-1 sell

```
library(blotter)
library(xts)
set.seed(1)
times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00"), length = 30, by = "sec")
price <- round(cumsum(rnorm(30))+999,2)

signal <- rep(0,30)
signal[5] <- 1  # open long
signal[15] <- -1  # close long open short

dat <- xts(cbind(price,signal),order.by = times)



initDate='1997-12-31'
initEq=1000

currency("USD")
stock("dat",currency="USD",multiplier=1)

ltportfolio='my'
ltaccount='my'

initPortf(ltportfolio,'dat', initDate=initDate)
initAcct(ltaccount,portfolios='my', initDate=initDate, initEq=initEq)
verbose=TRUE


for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  
  CurrentDate <- time(dat)[i]
  # getEndEq(ltaccount, CurrentDate)
  
  # get current open position
  open_position <- getPosQty(ltportfolio, Symbol='dat', Date=CurrentDate)

#####################  
##### open long #####
##################### 
  if(dat$signal[i]==1){
    # if there is an open short position, close it
    if(open_position < 0){
      addTxn(ltaccount, 
             Symbol='dat', 
             TxnDate=CurrentDate, 
             TxnPrice=dat$price[i],
             TxnQty = -open_position , 
             TxnFees=0, 
             verbose=verbose)
    }
    
    # open long position
    addTxn(ltaccount, 
           Symbol='dat', 
           TxnDate=CurrentDate, 
           TxnPrice=dat$price[i],
           TxnQty = 1 , 
           TxnFees=0, 
           verbose=verbose)
  }
######################
##### open short #####
######################
  if(dat$signal[i]==-1){
    # if there is an open long position, close it
    if(open_position > 0){
      addTxn(ltaccount, 
             Symbol='dat', 
             TxnDate=CurrentDate, 
             TxnPrice=dat$price[i],
             TxnQty = -open_position , 
             TxnFees=0, 
             verbose=verbose)
    }
    
    # open short position
    addTxn(ltaccount, 
           Symbol='dat', 
           TxnDate=CurrentDate, 
           TxnPrice=dat$price[i],
           TxnQty = -1 , 
           TxnFees=0, 
           verbose=verbose)
  }
}


updatePortf(ltportfolio, Dates = CurrentDate)
updateAcct(ltaccount, Dates = CurrentDate)
updateEndEq(ltaccount, Dates = CurrentDate)
```

the problem is with this chart

```
 chart.Posn(ltportfolio, Symbol = 'dat')
```

[image]

It does not show either accumulated profit or drawdown, but it should do so by default, at least [in all examples](https://github.com/braverock/blotter/tree/master/demo) it does so.

That is, the graph should look like this by default
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great job on providing a reproducible example! The issue is that you're providing `Dates = CurrentDate` in the call to `updatePorf()`. That means you're only valuing your trades on one date (`CurrentDate`). You probably mean to value them on every date. You can do that by omitting the `Dates` argument.

```r
updatePortf(ltportfolio)
updateAcct(ltportfolio)
updateEndEq(ltportfolio)

chart.Posn(ltportfolio, Symbol = 'dat')
```

Now the chart has cumulative PnL and drawdown.

[image]